# Are the requirements for an initial type rating the same across types?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, type-ratings

If a pilot wishes to obtain an initial FAA type rating - say, for a Boeing 737 - are the requirements to obtain that rating the same as if they were getting a type rating for an Airbus A320? If they are different, where can these requirements be found?

Assume that in both cases the pilot is ATP-rated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't matter whether you are a Private pilot or an ATP, the requirements for a type rating are in the [Airline Transport Pilot and Aircraft Type Rating Practical Test Standards](http://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_standards/media/FAA-S-8081-5F.pdf), which apply regardless of the aircraft type.

In the PTS, it says:

> **Practical Test Book Description**
>
> This practical test book contains the Airline Transport Pilot and 
>   Aircraft Type Rating Practical Test Standards—Airplane.  The Airline
>   Transport Pilot and Aircraft Type Rating Practical Test 
>   Standards—Airplane includes Areas of Operation and Tasks for the 
>   initial issuance of an airline transport pilot certificate and for the
>   addition of category, class, and aircraft type ratings to an airline 
>   transport pilot certificate. These Areas of Operation and Tasks also 
>   apply for the issuance of an airplane type rating to a private or 
>   commercial pilot certificate.

You basically cover everything needed for the ATP.  The differences between the different airplanes come out during the practical test just like they do for any other checkride.  The examiner (who will be typed in the airplane) asks you about the things that are specific to each airplane, but this isn't really a lot different than him asking you questions specific to a Cessna or a Piper during your private pilot checkride.

The PTS specifies general *Areas of Operation*'s instead of saying exactly what needs to be tested for every aircraft type.

Here they are for a type rating:

> **Section 1: Preflight Preparation**
>
> **Areas of Operation**
>
> I. Preflight Preparation
>   Task A: Equipment Examination
>   Task B: Performance and Limitations 
>   Task C: Water and Seaplane Characteristics (AMES/ASES)
>   Task D: Seaplane Bases, Maritime Rules, and Aids to Marine Navigation (AMES/ASES)
>
> **Section 2: Preflight Procedures, Inflight Maneuvers, and Postflight Procedures**
>
> **Areas of Operation**
>
> II. Preflight Procedures
>   Task A: Preflight Inspection
>   Task B: Powerplant Start 
>   Task C: TAXIING 
>   Task D: Sailing (AMES/ASES)
>   Task E: Seaplane Base/Water Landing Site Markings and Lighting (AMES, ASES)
>   Task F: Pre-Takeoff Checks
>
> III. Takeoff and Departure Phase
>   Task A: Normal and Crosswind Takeoff
>   Task B: Glassy Water Takeoff and Climb (AMES/ASES)
>   Task C: Rough Water Takeoff and Climb (AMES/ASES)
>   Task D: Confined-Area Takeoff and Climb (AMES/ASES)
>   Task E: Instrument Takeoff
>   Task F: Powerplant Failure during Takeoff
>   Task G: Rejected Takeoff
>   Task H: Departure Procedures
>
> IV. Inflight Maneuvers
>   Task A: Steep Turns
>   Task B: Approaches to Stalls and Stall Recovery
>   Task C: Powerplant Failure—Multiengine Airplane
>   Task D: Powerplant Failure—Single–Engine Airplane
>   Task E: Specific Flight Characteristics
>   Task F: Recovery from Unusual Attitudes
>
> V. Instrument Procedures
>   Task A: Standard Terminal Arrival/Flight Management System Procedures
>   Task B: Holding
>   Task C: Precision Approaches (PA) 
>   Task D: Nonprecision Approaches (NPA)
>   Task E: Circling Approach 
>   Task F: Missed Approach
>
> VI. Landings and Approaches to Landings
>   Task A: Normal and Crosswind Approaches and Landings
>   Task B: Landing from a Precision Approach
>   Task C: Approach and Landing with (Simulated) Powerplant Failure—Multiengine Airplane
>   Task D: Landing From a Circling Approach
>   Task E: Rough Water Approach and Landing (AMES/ASES)
>   Task F: Glassy Water Approach And Landing (AMES/ASES) 
>   Task G: Confined-Area Approach and Landing (AMES/ASES)
>   Task H: Rejected Landing
>   Task I: Landing from a No Flap or a Nonstandard Flap Approach
>
> VII. Normal and Abnormal Procedures
>   Task A: Normal and Abnormal Procedures
>
> VIII. Emergency Procedures
>   Task A: Emergency Procedures
>
> IX. Postflight Procedures
>   Task A: After-Landing Procedures
>   Task B: Anchoring (AMES/ASES)
>   Task C: Docking and Mooring (AMES/ASES)
>   Task D: Beaching (AMES/ASES)
>   Task E: Ramping (AMES/ASES)
>   Task F: Parking and Securing