# How many type ratings are pilots allowed to hold at once?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, commercial-aviation, type-ratings

I think i've read that the B787 has a common type rating with the B767 and B777. But I also think I've read that pilots are only allowed to fly two types of aircraft at a time...

So when they go to fly the 787, do they have to give up one of the their ratings if say they were previously allowed to fly the 767 and 777? Would the same still apply for say a B757 and B767 which have very similar flightdecks?

EASA and FAA perspectives would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of type ratings that a person can hold. The [world record](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/records-2000/most-faa-aircraft-pilot-type-ratings-by-an-individual/) for most type ratings held by an individual currently stands at 105!

For safety reasons, most airlines only allow a pilot to be *currently assigned* to two aircraft types at one time so that they don't start to confuse the different airplanes and mix things up. This isn't a regulation though, at least in the US.

In your example, those airplanes are the same **type** so would only count as one of the two that they could be assigned to, but this will vary based on individual airline policy and the complexity of the differences between the actual aircraft involved.

Comment: thanks, that clarifies everything :) on the topic of that world record holder, is there a minimum that must be flown on each type, or is it only overall hours which count?

Comment: @Manfred To get a type rating, you just have to complete training and a checkride.  You never even have to fly the airplane!  [Another answer of mine](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1575/69) shows what is required to obtain a type rating.

Comment: wow, that's interesting, thanks :D

Comment: It should be noted that being rated and current are two different things. You never lose a rating earned (at least in FAA-land), but that doesn’t mean you’re legal to use it.

Comment: It is very impressive to have so many type ratings.  I counted several Bell and Sikorsky helicopter type ratings that could be below 12,500 lbs.  If those were earned today, would not be on the pilot certificate.  Do I think his 105 types are valid?  Yes!  He earned them using the rules at the time.  It may be difficult to beat using current FAA rules though.

Comment: There are ICAO countries that will remove a type rating from a pilot certificate when they are no longer current.  Mexico comes to mind.  I am also thinking some EU countries do this as well.