# How many aircraft types can a 135 pilot be assigned to?

Tags: faa-regulations, far-135

Is there a limit to how many aircraft types a §135 operator may assign a pilot to fly? In other words, could a pilot type rated to fly—for example—a Learjet 75, Citation X, and Challenger 300 be assigned by the §135 certificate holder to fly all three of these types in §135 operations at any given time? Would that pilot be limited—for example—to only two types at a time for the purposes of §135 flight operations? I am not considering flight assignments that are to be conducted under §91. Is there a difference if the pilot is assigned as PIC or SIC?

I ask because my understanding has been that a §135 operator may assign a pilot to a maximum of two aircraft types at a time. However, I cannot find any documentation or discussion to support this.

Edit: To be clear, I am *not* asking about how many type ratings an FAA certified pilot is allowed to acquire in total (the answer to that question is: no limit). I am asking about what §135 operators are authorized to do, as far as assigning flight crew to various aircraft types.

Comment: Are you asking for a regulation that specifies a maximum, or are you asking specifically about airline procedures?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many type ratings are pilots allowed to hold at once?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-many-type-ratings-are-pilots-allowed-to-hold-at-once)

Comment: @GdD, no, I am familiar with that question, which deals with the pilot certification issue of how many type ratings an FAA certified pilot may acquire (answer: unlimited). My question is about hat §135 operators are authorized to do, as far as assigning flight crew to various aircraft types. I think I have made my question clear—though I acknowledge the issue is obscure, but I am open to suggestions of ways to clarify it?

Comment: I don't believe that there is any regulation that limits the number of assigned aircraft of pilots for a Part 135 operator. Any limit would probably be in the company SOP's.

Comment: @RonBeyer I misspoke. I meant to say NOT asking for regulation. I'm aware there are no such regulations. I will delete and replace that comment with the correct wording.

Comment: @RonBeyer I am *not* asking for regulation; I am asking for guidance such as that given in FSIMS. I am not asking about airline procedures; I am asking about what §135 operators are authorized to do.

Comment: I don't believe there is a limit in the FSIMS documents (or other FAA guidance) either... the issue is currency. The more aircraft a pilot is assigned, the more time they need to spend on currency requirements. This *functionally* limits the pilots to 1 or 2 types that they can keep current and still be useful as a revenue pilot. I'm guessing some of the training captains may have 3 or 4 assigned aircraft types.

Answer (score 2):

There is no FAA regulation limit for the number of types a Part 135 pilot can be assigned to, providing all training programs are followed.  Insurance and safety auditing companies usually have guidelines requiring no more than 2 types to be assigned at a time so the 2 aircraft limit has become something of an industry standard.

There may be non-US regulations that address this issue.